# PHPExcel: how to get cell's fill color, that is set using conditional formatting?

Tags: phpexcel

I have a cell that has conditional formatting applied and a static color (green). The cell is red, if you view it in Excel (because of conditional formatting). If I use `getStartColor()`, I get the static color: green. If I use `getEndColor()` I get white. I'd like to get the red one.

How can I do that?

Comment: Start here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996384/excel-2007-conditional-formatting-how-to-get-cell-color and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408899/how-do-i-find-the-fill-colour-value-of-a-conditionally-formatted-cell-in-excel-2

Comment: Are you using getStartColor() on the cells' style or on the conditional style?

Comment: @DavidZemens: I'm talking about PHPExcel, not just Excel.

Comment: @Mark yeah, on the style, not the conditional style. Will read your answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$conditionalStyles = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('B2')
    ->getConditionalStyles();
```

will return the conditional styles for the specified cell as an array:

You can loop through those, using `getConditionType()`, `getOperatorType()` and `getConditions()` (which can return an array of conditions) , etc to identify the conditional rule, test if the cell value matches that rule, and then use `getStyle()` to retrieve the style details

Comment: Huh, this looks like a lot of work. Maybe this can be integrated into PHPExcel? This conditions can sometimes be very complex...

Comment: Possibly, in PHPExcel 2.0.0 - I'll look at the options, because it would also be potentially useful for the HTML and PDF Writers. Note that Conditional styles will be changing (internally) within PHPExcel for the 2.0.0 version anyway, as we're looking at allowing a single style to be set for multiple cells without needing to clone the conditional